# Microsoft NuGet targets Error while building Project from Teamcity

Tags: command-line, msbuild, nuget, teamcity, .net-4.6.1

I attempted in building the .NET Standard Library Project using .NET Framework 4.6.1 from Command prompt using **MSBuild Commmand**. I manage to succeed building the project from command prompt.

I tried the same MSBuild command to build the project from **Teamcity** **Command line build step**, but ended up getting the following error:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(140,5): error : The package Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility 
   with version 1.0.1 could not be found in C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\. Run a NuGet package restore to download the package.
```

I tried Restoring `nuget.exe restore mysolution.sln` but noting works.

Please help me to compile the solution from Teamcity command line step. Its strange to get compiled from command prompt but not from teamcity command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a known issue in NuGet when restoring packages using the LocalSystem account wherein the packages cannot be accessed under the `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages` folder, even though account permissions should allow it (see [this GH issue](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4277)). The current recommended workaround is to use the `NUGET_PACKAGES` environment variable to specify another location for the packages (e.g. `C:\NuGet\packages`).